# cross sell, up sell page? any way to do it better than default to increase sales?

Tags: cross-sells, upselling

Ideally - I would love to add an extra step in the check-out (I don't have a one-page checkout) just as they have it working on proflowers.com but I hear that's rather complicated. So - any solution which will make my cross sell items more visible than the default would be appreciated. I did a search for extensions on Magento Connect but didn't really find anything interesting. Just to explain it correctly - I want something come up for the customer to clearly see that would say something like:

***Make it extra special! Add options to include with your gift:***

and then add *Teddy Bears, Chocolates, Cookies, Balloons, etc.*

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I don't want any automatic cross-up-selling suggestions - I want to be able to select what I want to show/sell...

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to customize the checkout. That is always a challenge.
Also, keep in mind, that during checkout, once you select your shipping and save, your calculations are already set.  Having someone add something at the end of the checkout would require them to walk through the steps one more time.

It may be better to have them land on a page, before taking them to checkout, OR adding a new 1st step to the checkout so things can be added without the customer having to walk through checkout 2x's.

Any of these will require some work.  I am not sure if there is some extension you can purchase, but a qualified developer/company can certainly do this for you.

Also, it would be pretty hard to find a Magento connect prebuild extension that will do *exactly* what you want but I would start there.  That will probably be the most economical approach.  However, I would recommend a custom designed solution.  This way you can rest assured it will work on your site.